# How do you call a funcion inside a for loop in Arduino?

Tags: function, for-loop, arduino

I am programming my Arduino Uno with an ultrasonic sensor to sense the distance from it and print that on the serial plotter / monitor, at the same time 4 LEDS are blinking. I am not having any problems with them doing their thing at the same time, but I want the ultrasonic sensor to sense more than one time after the LEDS blink once. Here is the code:

```
const int red1 = 4;
const int red2 = 5;
const int yellow1 = 6;
const int yellow2 = 7;
const int echo = 10;
const int trig = 9;
const int buzzer = 11;
int maxCmAway = 50;

float duration_us, distance_cm;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin (9600);
  pinMode(red1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(red2, OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(yellow1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(yellow2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(trig, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echo, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(yellow1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(yellow2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(red1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(red2, HIGH);
  for(int i=0; i<6; i++) {
    if (checkDist() > maxCmAway) {
      blip();
    } else {
      noTone(buzzer);
      delay(250);
    }
  }
  digitalWrite(red1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(red2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(yellow1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(yellow2, HIGH);
  for(int i=0; i<6; i++) {
    if (checkDist() > maxCmAway) {
      blip();
    } else {
      noTone(buzzer);
      delay(250);
    }
  }

int checkDist() {
    // generate 10-microsecond pulse to TRIG pin
  digitalWrite(trig, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(trig, LOW);

  // measure duration of pulse from ECHO pin
  duration_us = pulseIn(echo, HIGH);

  // calculate the distance
  distance_cm = 0.017 * duration_us;

  // print the value to Serial Monitor
  if (distance_cm < maxCmAway) {
    Serial.print("distance: ");
    Serial.print(distance_cm);
    Serial.println(" cm");
    Serial.print("real: ");
    Serial.print(distance_cm);
    Serial.println(" cma");
  } else {
    Serial.println("distance: 0 cm");
    Serial.print("real: ");
    Serial.print(distance_cm);
    Serial.println(" cma");
  }

  return distance_cm;
}

int blip() {
    tone(buzzer, 800);
    delay(50);
    tone(buzzer, 600);
    delay(100);
    tone(buzzer, 800);
    delay(100);
    noTone(buzzer);
    return 1;
}
```

The code that is messing up is after all the digitalWrites in the loop() function in the for loop where it says `if (checkDist() > maxCmAway)`. The error is " 'checkDist' was not declared in this scope " I know what this error means, but I don't know any other way to fix it besides copying and pasting the if statement 5 times.

When I look this up on Google, it just shows a bunch of things about the setup() and loop() functions.
And the other thing I tried is putting the word 'global' before the function I am calling, but 'global' does not look like it is a keyword.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a closing bracket for `void loop()`

If you look at the other error messages above "Compilation error", you should see one that says `error: expected '}' at end of input`. If not, you can go to preferences and enable verbose out for compilation.